# Python inconsistent UnboundLocalError behavior. One local variable throws error while the other does not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting `UnboundLocalError` for one of the variables but not the other one.

This is the code that confuses me:

```
tokens=[]
token_count = 0

def extend():
    for word in line.split():
        tokens.append(word)
        token_count += 1

lines = ['this is one line', 'this is another line']
for line in lines:
    extend()
    print(tokens)
```

Running this you would get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'token_count' referenced before assignment
```

But removing `token_count += 1` line makes the code run fine.
I understand that this can be fixed by adding a `global token_count` after function definition.

What I have trouble understanding is why Python is not complaining about the other variables (e.g., `line` in `for word in line.split()` and `tokens`). These variables are all defined outside this function and if I'm getting Local variable error for one, I should get it for the other too.

Any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Because you're not *assigning* to line or tokens. It's not inconsistent, you're doing different things.

Answer (score 1):

Variables inside a function will be inherited from an outer scope if not assigned within the function.  However, if you do assign within a function, then that variable is local (unless you use a `nonlocal` or `global` statement as appropriate), and you cannot use its value before you have assigned it.  Where you are doing `token_count += 1`, you are trying to look up the existing value (in order to add 1 to it) before any value has been assigned within the function, and this will fail.

It is not normally good practice to make use of global variables; a better to the problem would be to return a value.  For example:

```
def extend(tokens, line, token_count):
    "extend tokens by the words in line; also return new token count"
    for word in line.split():
        tokens.append(word)
        token_count += 1
    return token_count

lines = ['this is one line', 'this is another line']
for line in lines:
    token_count = extend(tokens, line, token_count)
    print(tokens)
```

This function does not make any use of variables inherited from an outer scope; everything is local to the function or a function parameter.

In the case of `token_count`, it is a parameter, but you are reassigning it within the function. This is fine, but note that it will not change the value of `token_count` in the main program. This is done later, by assigning it to the returned value in the main program (see `token_count = extend(...)` line).

In the case of `tokens`, you are mutating an existing mutable object (a list) by calling its `append` method, not reassigning it (you are not doing `tokens = ...`).  The updated value is visible also in the main program.

Note that here, the function both modifies a mutable argument (`tokens`) and also returns a value. This is a little bit unusual, so to avoid any confusion it is good to state explicitly that this is what it is doing - hence the docstring at the start of the function.

If you need to return more than one value in this way, then pack them into a tuple, which you can unpack in the main program.

---

*Note: in this case, the value of `token_count` could instead simply be obtained using `len(tokens)` rather than have a separate variable for it at all, but for sake of example, the code does not make use of that fact.*